# Variable value can not pass in AzureCLI@1 in yaml file

Tags: yaml, azure-pipelines, azure-cli

When I create a task (AzureCLI@1), I wanted to assign a value to a variable, but the error saying the command appId is unrecognized. What could be the issues?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fzGUa.png)

What cause this issue?

Comment: can you share actual FULL error text, not your interpretation of it

Comment: 'appId' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Comment: Hi, thank you for replying this question! I actually find out the reason because of the Windows agent pool I was using.

Comment: consider adding an answer to this question or deleting this question then, thanks! ps. glad you solved it

Comment: Please share code, text, logs and errors as text (in code fence) not as image

Answer (score 0):

The issue is solved. It causes because the agent pool is using Windows instead of Linux. Apparently, Azcli@1 is more suitable for Linux-based but Azcli@2 is more suitable for Windows-based.